# Ошибка при запуске docker run hello-world

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

такая проблема, когда я пытаюсь запустить команду docker run hello-world, то у меня выдает вот такую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же пробовал войти в профиль, но выдавало вот такое, после этого команды не работают:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто подсказать как решить проблему?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

Comment: По поводу того, что чего-то нет в PATH, посмотрите что с этой переменной делается в ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile и /etc/profile

Comment: судя по первому скриншоту вы установили доскер, но не раздали права пользьзователю. Посмотрите руководство по инсталляциимоп ссылке, которую написал @InDevX